# Making a function chainable with then()

Tags: javascript, promise

I have a function that uses fetch() to get a value from a database, which is then used to update an element on my page:

```
function AjaxUpdate(_element, _url, _form_data) {
  if (!_element) return; // Nothing to update.
  if (concurrency++ == 0)
    LoadStatus(_form_data === undefined ? "Loading..." : "Processing...");
  fetch(_url, {
    method: _form_data === undefined ? "GET" : "POST",
    body: _form_data,
  })
    .then((response) => response.text())
    .then((text) => {
      if (_element.nodeName == "INPUT") _element.value = text;
      else _element.innerHTML = text;
      /* inserted */ return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        resolve(text);
      });
    })
    .catch((error) => alert(error.message))
    .finally(() => {
      if (--concurrency == 0) LoadStatus("");
    });
}
```

I like this function to be chainable, by calling it like this:

```
const company_form = document.getElementById("company_form");
const company_properties = document.getElementById("company_properties");
const cmc_info = document.getElementById("cmc_info");
AjaxUpdate(company_properties, "company?action=edit&CompanyID=12345", new FormData(company_form))
    .then(text => { AjaxUpdate(cmc_info, "company?action=editcmc&CompanyID=12345"); });
```

The initial call is a POST (updates the database) and the second call should wait for the first to complete before starting. To do so I inserted a `return new Promise()` statement, but that does not work as expected. The initial function call is executed (database is updated) but then I get an error message "TypeError: function AjaxUpdate(...) is undefined".
The single call version is used many times and runs OK; when I put a `then()` at the end, it breaks down.

Could anyone give me a push...?

Comment: Just as a side note, I really recommend using braces around your `if`/`else` blocks, even if single lined. Although it seems fine when writing, it can introduce rather stupid bugs when refactoring/maintaining (see https://www.imperialviolet.org/2014/02/22/applebug.html for instance).

Comment: `AjaxUpdate` doesn't return anything, much less a promise. It would return a promise if you did `return fetch(...).then(...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `return` statement is scoped under the *callback* of the `then` invocation. So `AjaxUpdate` is not actually returning that `Promise` but an implicit `undefined`.

I suggest you three possible solutions.

1. Return the `fetch` promise chain result

   ```
   function AjaxUpdate(_element, _url, _form_data) {
     if (!_element) {
       // return a dummy Promise
       return Promise.resolve(/* whatever you want as a default*/);
     }
     // ...

     // Returning fetch promise chain
     return fetch(...)
       .then(...)
       .then((text) => {
           // ...
           return text;
           // text will be passed from the next `then` invocation
       });
   }
   ```
2. Return a whole Promise which resolves whenever you need to

   ```
   function AjaxUpdate(_element, _url, _form_data) {
     return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
           if (!_element) {
               resolve(/* Any default value ...*/);
           // or even reject();
           }
           // ...

           fetch(...)
           .then(...)
           .then((text) => {
               // ...
               resolve(text);
           })
           .catch(reject)
           .finally(...);
     });
   }
   ```
3. Make `AjaxUpdate` async so it will return an implicit Promise

   ```
   async function AjaxUpdate(_element, _url, _form_data) {
       if (!_element) {
           return;
       }

       // ...

       try {
           const response = await fetch(...);
           const text = await response.text();

           // ...

           return text;
       } catch (e) {
           // ...
       }

       // Finally
       // ...
   }
   ```

Hope it helps.

Comment: It did help! Thanks very much. I just didn't see what I was doing wrong. It is clear now!

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a return statement to AjaxUpdate for the case where you fetch data. And for consistency, you should return a promise in the `if (!_element)` case too.

```
function AjaxUpdate(_element, _url, _form_data) {
  if (!_element) return Promise.resolve();
//                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^---- MODIFIED
  if (concurrency++ == 0)
    LoadStatus(_form_data === undefined ? "Loading..." : "Processing...");
  return fetch(_url, {
//^^^^^^---- ADDED
    method: _form_data === undefined ? "GET" : "POST",
    body: _form_data,
  })
    .then((response) => response.text())
    .then((text) => {
      if (_element.nodeName == "INPUT") _element.value = text;
      else _element.innerHTML = text;
      return text;
    })
    .catch((error) => alert(error.message))
    .finally(() => {
      if (--concurrency == 0) LoadStatus("");
    });
}
```